# Model_Fechamento - Customizar Código

Tags: php, codeigniter

Senhores, tenho o seguinte código PHP:

```
# Fechamento Chamada
public function fechamentoChamada($data_inicial = null, $data_final = null, $idCliente = null, $idFuncionario = null, $view = null, $tipo_chamada = null){
    ////// ?view=&tipo_chamada=0&idCliente=&idFuncionario=&data_inicial=2015-06-01&data_final=2015-06-30

    if(!empty($tipo_chamada)) $sqlConjunto = "AND c.tipo_chamada = '".$tipo_chamada."'"; else $sqlConjunto = "";
    if(!empty($tipo_chamada)) $sqlConjuntoView = "AND tipo_chamada = '".$tipo_chamada."'"; else $sqlConjuntoView = "";


    # seleciona somente com a data
    if(empty($idFuncionario) and empty($view) and empty($idCliente)){
        $sql = "SELECT c.*, cl.*, cl.razaosocial as nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) as totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, ce.idCedente, ce.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.idParametro, p.parametro as notaFiscal FROM chamada AS c, cliente as cl, cedente as ce, parametro as p WHERE c.data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND cl.idCliente = c.idCliente AND cl.codCedente = ce.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro {$sqlConjunto} GROUP BY c.idCliente";
    }   

    # seleciona com idFuncionario
    if(is_numeric($idFuncionario) && $view=="" && $idCliente==""){
        $sql = "SELECT c.*, cl.*, cl.razaosocial as nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) as totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, ce.idCedente, ce.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.idParametro, p.parametro as notaFiscal FROM chamada AS c, cliente as cl, cedente as ce, parametro as p WHERE c.data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND c.idFuncionario = {$idFuncionario} AND cl.idCliente = c.idCliente AND cl.codCedente = ce.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro {$sqlConjunto} GROUP BY c.idCliente";
    }   
    # seleciona com idFuncionario & idCliente
    if(isset($idFuncionario) && $view=="" && isset($idCliente)){
        $sql = "SELECT c.*, cl.*, cl.razaosocial as nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) as totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, ce.idCedente, ce.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.idParametro, p.parametro as notaFiscal FROM chamada AS c, cliente as cl, cedente as ce, parametro as p WHERE c.data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND c.idFuncionario = {$idFuncionario} AND cl.idCliente = {$idCliente} AND cl.codCedente = ce.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro {$sqlConjunto} GROUP BY c.idCliente";
    }
    # seleciona com idCliente, idFuncionario e visualiza todos (relatorio interno)
    if(isset($idFuncionario) && $view=="todos" && isset($idCliente)){
        $sql = "SELECT c.*, cl.*, cl.razaosocial as nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) as totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, ce.idCedente, ce.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.idParametro, p.parametro as notaFiscal FROM chamada AS c, cliente as cl, cedente as ce, parametro as p WHERE c.data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND c.idFuncionario = {$idFuncionario} AND cl.idCliente = {$idCliente} AND cl.codCedente = ce.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro {$sqlConjunto} GROUP BY c.idCliente";
    }   

    # seleciona com idCliente e idFuncionario vazio
    if(is_numeric($idCliente) and empty($idFuncionario)){
        $sql = "SELECT c.*, cl.*, cl.razaosocial as nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) as totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, ce.idCedente, ce.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.idParametro, p.parametro as notaFiscal FROM chamada AS c, cliente as cl, cedente as ce, parametro as p WHERE c.data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND cl.idCliente = '".$idCliente."' AND cl.codCedente = ce.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro GROUP BY c.idCliente";

    }

//  echo $sql;


    $consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();

        foreach($consulta as &$valor){

            if(empty($idFuncionario) and empty($view) and empty($idCliente)){
                $sql = "SELECT *, sum(valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, count(idCliente) as totalOsBase FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' {$sqlConjuntoView}";
                $valor->totalFechamento = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
            }

            if(is_numeric($idCliente) and empty($idFuncionario)){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND idCliente = '".$idCliente."' {$sqlConjuntoView}";
                $valor->totalFechamento = $this->db->query($sql)->result(); 

                $sql_totais = "SELECT *, sum(valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, count(idCliente) as totalOsBase FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND idCliente = '".$idCliente."' {$sqlConjuntoView} ";
                $valor->totalFechamentoTotais = $this->db->query($sql_totais)->row();   

            }

            if(empty($idCliente) and is_numeric($idFuncionario)){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND idFuncionario = '".$idFuncionario."' {$sqlConjuntoView}";
                $valor->totalFechamento = $this->db->query($sql)->result(); 

                $sql_totais = "SELECT *, sum(valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, count(idFuncionario) as totalOsBase FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND idFuncionario = '".$idFuncionario."' {$sqlConjuntoView}";
                $valor->totalFechamentoTotais = $this->db->query($sql_totais)->row();


            }

            if(is_numeric($idCliente) and is_numeric($idFuncionario)){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND idCliente = {$idCliente} AND idFuncionario = '".$idFuncionario."' {$sqlConjuntoView}";
                $valor->totalFechamento = $this->db->query($sql)->result(); 

                $sql_totais = "SELECT *, sum(valor_empresa) as valorEmpresa, count(idFuncionario) as totalOsBase FROM chamada WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."' AND idFuncionario = '".$idFuncionario."' AND idCliente = {$idCliente} {$sqlConjuntoView}";
                $valor->totalFechamentoTotais = $this->db->query($sql_totais)->row();
            }


        }

    return $consulta;

}
```

Gostaria de customizar, pra não ficar este monte de if() else () e nem estes vários SQL, sei que dá pra fazer de uma forma no SQL pra fazer uma consulta só, porém, não sei fazer... Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ajudar para alguém, desenvolvi essa solução:

```
public function fechamentoChamada($data_inicial = null, $data_final = null, $idCliente = null, $idFuncionario = null, $view = null, $tipo_chamada = null)
{
    # adiciona itens no SQL
    $sqlAdd = "WHERE c.data BETWEEN '{$data_inicial}' AND '{$data_final}'";
    if(empty($idCliente)) $sqlAdd .= " AND c.idCliente = cl.idCliente AND cl.codCedente = cd.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro AND c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario"; else $sqlAdd .= " AND c.idCliente = {$idCliente} AND cl.idCliente = {$idCliente} AND cl.codCedente = cd.idCedente AND cl.nota = p.idParametro AND c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario";  
    if(empty($idFuncionario)) $sqlAdd .= ""; else $sqlAdd .= " AND c.idFuncionario = {$idFuncionario}"; 
    if(empty($tipo_chamada)) $sqlAdd .= ""; else $sqlAdd .= " AND c.tipo_chamada = {$tipo_chamada}"; 

    if(empty($view)) $sqlAdd .= " GROUP BY c.idCliente"; elseif($view=='todos') $sqlAdd .= "";

    # adiciona itens na consulta *
    $sqlAddConsulta = "";
    if(empty($idCliente) and empty($view)) $sqlAddConsulta .= "c.idCliente, c.*, cl.razaosocial AS nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) as totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) AS valorEmpresa, cd.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.parametro as notaFiscal, f.nome as nomeFuncionario"; elseif(empty($view)) $sqlAddConsulta .= "c.idCliente, c.*, cl.razaosocial AS nomeCliente, count(c.idCliente) AS totalOs, sum(c.valor_empresa) AS valorEmpresa, cd.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.parametro as notaFiscal, f.nome as nomeFuncionario";

    if($view=='todos') $sqlAddConsulta .= "c.idCliente, c.*, cl.razaosocial AS nomeCliente, cd.razaosocial as nomeFaturado, p.parametro as notaFiscal, f.nome as nomeFuncionario";

    # adiciona aliase
    $sqlAddAliase = ", cliente as cl, cedente as cd, parametro as p, funcionario as f";

    $sql = "SELECT {$sqlAddConsulta} FROM chamada AS c {$sqlAddAliase} {$sqlAdd}";
    $consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();

        foreach($consulta as &$valor){
            $sqlAdd = str_replace(" GROUP BY c.idCliente", "", $sqlAdd);
            $sql = "SELECT {$sqlAddConsulta} FROM chamada AS c {$sqlAddAliase} {$sqlAdd}";
            $valor->retorno = $this->db->query($sql)->row();

            $sqlR = "SELECT {$sqlAddConsulta}, count(c.idCliente) as totalOsGeral, sum(c.valor_empresa) as valorEmpresaGeral FROM chamada AS c {$sqlAddAliase} {$sqlAdd}";
            $valor->retornoR = $this->db->query($sqlR)->row();              
        }

    return $consulta;
}
```